# need help figuring out why method updating_sitting and custmor_increment are not adding and printing out the way they should

Tags: python

```
class Restaurant():
    """intalizing attributes rest._type and food_type"""
    def __init__(self,resturant_type,*food_type):
         self.rest_type = resturant_type
         self.food = food_type
         self.number_severd = 0 
    def opening(self):
        """Letting people know that the resturant is open"""
        print(self.rest_type.title() + " is now open")
    def describing_rest(self):
       """telling you about resturant"""
       print("\nWelcome to " + self.rest_type.title() + 
             " here are what we have on the menu today: ")
       for self.foods in self.food:
           print("-" + self.foods)
   def updating_sitting(self,new_chart):
         """updating sitting chart"""
        self.number_served = new_chart
   def custmor_increment(self,addition):
    """add number to custmor count"""
       self.number_severd += addition
 rest = Restaurant('High Spot','Turkey sandwich','pizza','deserts')     
 rest.opening()
 rest.describing_rest()
 rest.number_severd = 230
 print("we have " + str(rest.updating_sitting(400)))
 print("now we have " + str(rest.custmor_increment(100)))
```

i need help figuring out how to method updating_sitting to print out how many are sitting now
and for custmor_increment to print what the new amount of custmors there is.

Comment: Could you please specify more clearly what is happening and what you are try to achieve?

Comment: yes sorry i was trying to get method 'updating_sitting' to be able to print out current number of customers and then when i add a increment with 'customer_increment' to then print the new value

Comment: Did the answer below solve it?

Comment: yes it did ,thank you for attempting to help me.

Answer (score 1):

To print how many are sitting, the methods need to return `self.number_served`.

You also need to fix the typos `number_severd` and your indentation.

```
class Restaurant():
    def __init__(self,resturant_type,*food_type):
        """intalizing attributes rest._type and food_type"""
        self.rest_type = resturant_type
        self.food = food_type
        self.number_served = 0 

    def opening(self):
        """Letting people know that the resturant is open"""
        print(self.rest_type.title() + " is now open")

    def describing_rest(self):
        """telling you about resturant"""
        print("\nWelcome to " + self.rest_type.title() + 
              " here are what we have on the menu today: ")
        for self.foods in self.food:
            print("-" + self.foods)

    def updating_sitting(self,new_chart):
        """updating sitting chart"""
        self.number_served = new_chart
        return self.number_served

    def custmor_increment(self,addition):
        """add number to custmor count"""
        self.number_served += addition
        return self.number_served

rest = Restaurant('High Spot','Turkey sandwich','pizza','deserts')     
rest.opening()
rest.describing_rest()
rest.number_served = 230
print("we have " + str(rest.updating_sitting(400)))
print("now we have " + str(rest.custmor_increment(100)))
```

BTW, the correct spelling of "custmor" is "customer"